# Angular 2 have selection box have the default value

Tags: angular

I am trying to set the default value of the model driven form to always be Public, but it always shows up blank when I view it. If it was just with regular html it would be with the selected="Public" but it looks like the formControlName overrides that.

```
<select formControlName="privacy">
      <option [value]="2">Public</option>
      <option [value]="3">Friends</option>
      <option [value]="1">Private</option>
</select>
```

compontent.ts

```
this.wallPost= fb.group({
        "content": ["", Validators.required],
        "privacy": ["2"]
    });
```

Comment: How did you set the default value?

Comment: @Aravind this is for angular 2... the link is a question from 6 years ago

Comment: @Fals this.wallPost= fb.group({
        "content": ["", Validators.required],
        "privacy": ["2"]
    });  The select box is blank though, is there a way to make this value show as the the default selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller you should have something similar to:

```
this.wallPost = new FormGroup({
    privacy: new FormControl(2)
});
```

or

```
constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {}
this.wallPost = this.fb.group({
    privacy: [2]
});
```

Depending on whether you are creating the forms manually or using the form builder

Working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ItErRqhr0R8fk4cCLCpw?p=preview)

Comment: Hey Teddy, I think I should be more clear I want that value to appear on the form. right now it just blank then when I click the select box the options appeaer

Comment: Are you talking about the value on the wallPost FormGroup or that the select box is defaulted to 2?

Comment: ah I see what my problem was the default value I was setting as a string  "privacy": ['2'], I got it, thanks for the Plunker!